# Argos workflow: how do I build my workflow which runs a python script present in local image?

Tags: argo-workflows

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 OS, I have a local image (say myImage) with a bunch of python scripts (say /script/python01.py, /script/python02.py, etc) in it. Can someone guide me on how should argo workflow should look like to achieve:

1. Ask ARGOs to use my local image for python scripts (image: myImage - seems to be failing)
2. Call python scripts with or without arguments from above image, thinking to save its output back on Ubuntu OS.